# Detecting HP Envy x360 Ryzen5 3500u lid open/close?

Tags: linux, acpi

I tested a lot of environment like Ubuntu 19.10, Ubuntu Mint, ArchLinux, using Gnome, KDE Plasma etc.
And they didn't work except windows 10, like they do nothing when I open/close their lid as I expected, like acpid didn't handle events.

Does anyone here who is same situation or knows how to detect that events?
I appreciate your answering!

Comment: I suggest asking this question on unix.stackexchange.com. You can also see if this article on the Archlinux Wiki helps: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_Envy_X360_15-bq102ng. It mentions an `iio-sensor-proxy` package required to use the sensors hub, perhaps the lid detection is also covered?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and answer @bubenvb!
Well I'll try that package before ask in them.

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem. But thank you.